# Can urea crystals be used to generate pairs of entangled photons?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

According to this link https://patents.justia.com/patent/4639923, urea crystals can be used as optical parametric oscillators. The parametric oscillator uses a nonlinear crystal to convert the pump light into two signals, the sum of whose frequencies equals the frequency of the pump light. Thus, the oscillator produces two outputs, the signal, and a difference frequency, which is referred to as the idler. These frequencies can be tuned by index matching, as by rotating the crystal or by controlling the temperature of the crystal. Does this mean that urea crystals generate entanglement in the shape of pairs of signal and idler photons?

Answer (score 1):

In principle, sure, they can. The core mechanism is the same and if the crystal structure is correct and the nonlinear susceptibility is high enough (which is almost certainly the case if it's being used in OPAs) then there is no fundamental barrier.

On the other hand, phase-matching is a finicky business, particularly when you get down to the single-photon level, so when it comes to it, this need not be a realistic experiment, but then that's just how things go quite often.

Comment: The comparison of a 2 mm urea crystal with a 25 mm heated ammonium hihydrogen arsenate ADA crystal at 597 nm indicated that the nonlinear d14 coefficient of urea is 2.5 times the d36 of  ADA, about 1.4 pV/m. Powder measurements implied rather high values for the effective second-harmonic coefficients, ranging  from 1.7 pV/m to 7 pV/m at a wavelength of 1.064 micrometers. The measurements were carried out at a 90 deg phase matching angle, where walk-off and double refraction are not involved with the nonlinear generation.

Comment: Quoted from Nonlinear Optical Properties of Organic Molecules and Crystals, Volume 1 edited by D.S. Chemla. What do you think are those coefficients high?

Comment: That's much more detail than I know what to do with. For something that specific you really need a specialist. But more importantly, you really need a good reason to care, which isn't in evidence thus far.

Comment: It seems to me that you're completely underestimating the difficulty of the task (are you building this on an optical table? If not, how do you plan to deal with vibrations, and what level of interferometric stability are you aiming for?) but I do wish you good luck with the project.